# Image in LazyVStack using massive memory

Tags: swiftui, lazyvstack, sdwebimageswiftui

I make a simple app for displaying image list.
I use a LazyVStack inside ScrollView as container, ForEach to load every image
Images are loading from network, I have tried AsyncImage, but AsyncImage always loads image from network and no cache.
I have tried using [SDWebImageSwiftUI](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageSwiftUI) and [CachedAsyncImageView](https://github.com/lorenzofiamingo/swiftui-cached-async-image), both of them can get image from network with cache, and using lots of memory while scroll image.
here is the code

```swift
import CachedAsyncImage
import SDWebImageSwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var imageURLList: [String] = []
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
            VStack {
                HStack{
                    Button("test load") {
                        // parse the image list
                        Task{
                            do{
                                self.imageURLList = try await ImageListLoader.parseImageUrlList()
                            } catch {
                                print("error:\(error)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button("clear") {
                        self.imageURLList.removeAll()
                    }
                }
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(self.imageURLList, id: \.self) { url in
                            WebImage(url: URL(string: url))
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: geometryProxy.size.width)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image: memory usage]

I have tried to same url in forEach, and no memery issue

```swift
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(self.imageURLList, id: \.self) { url in
            WebImage(url: URL(string: url))
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: geometryProxy.size.width)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`List`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list) instead of LazyVStack this will manage the memory automatically as it works like [`UITableView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview) in the UIKit. In LazyVStack it will load the images at the same time as you scroll down & keep it in the memory for the duration.

Comment: I've tried List and nothing helps, the memory still keep growing while scroll List